# how to smooth scroll listview like ios in android?

Tags: android-listview, android-asynctask, scroll

I am use data from web using XML parser and setting data using custom adapter for this use asyncTask .
My problem is that some devices like Samsang duos,gallaxy work perfectly but on micromax devices it will not work properly.

My adapter is

```
public class HallBookingAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyHall> {

private Context context;

private ArrayList<MCCIAHall> halls;

private int resource;

MyHall objHall;

public int count;

View view;

public static Boolean isScrollingHalls=true;

LayoutInflater inflater;

static class HallBookingHolder
{
    public TextView txtTitle,txtLocation,txtCapacity,txtCapacityTitle;
    public ImageView imgHall;
    public LinearLayout hallBookingLayout;
}

public HallBookingAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<MyHall> halls) {
    super(context, resource, halls);

    this.context=context;
    this.halls=halls;
    this.resource=resource;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    count=halls.size();
    return halls.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    view=convertView;

    objHall=halls.get(position);

    HallBookingHolder holder=new HallBookingHolder();

    if (convertView==null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(resource, null);

        holder.txtTitle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtListHallTitle);
        holder.txtLocation=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtListHallLocation);
        holder.txtCapacity=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtListHallCapacity);
        holder.txtCapacityTitle=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtListHallCapacityHeadding);

        holder.imgHall=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgListHall);

         view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (HallBookingHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Creating the Font to the text
    Typeface tfLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    Typeface tfRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    Typeface tfsemiBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"OpenSans-Semibold.ttf");

    //Setting the font
    holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(tfRegular);
    holder.txtLocation.setTypeface(tfLight);
    holder.txtCapacity.setTypeface(tfsemiBold);
    holder.txtCapacityTitle.setTypeface(tfLight);

//Setting data to textview and image
    holder.txtTitle.setText(objHall.hallName);
    holder.txtLocation.setText(objHall.location);
    holder.txtCapacity.setText(objHall.capacity);

    //Using Guild Library Image Load using image web url
    String imgurl=objHall.getImageUrl();
    Glide.load(imgurl).centerCrop().into(holder.imgHall);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, HallDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read it [listview smooth-scrolling](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

> Using a background thread ("worker thread") removes strain from the
>   main thread so it can focus on drawing the UI. In many cases, using
>   AsyncTask provides a simple way to perform your work outside the main
>   thread. AsyncTask automatically queues up all the execute() requests
>   and performs them serially. This behavior is global to a particular
>   process and means you don’t need to worry about creating your own
>   thread pool.

check this too  http://www.itworld.com/development/380008/how-make-smooth-scrolling-listviews-android

Answer (score 0):

Put all your font styles in the `if (convertView==null) {}` block to set them only once. Now you are setting them every time a new row is created.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of quick tips to help you.

1. Reduce the number of conditions used in the getView of your adapter.
2. Check and reduce the number of garbage collection warnings that you get in the logs
3. If you're loading images while scrolling, get rid of them.
4. Set scrollingCache and animateCache to false (more on this later)
5. Simplify the hierarchy of the list view row layout
6. Use the view holder pattern

Here is a link to help you implement these tips.  [Link](http://leftshift.io/6-ways-to-make-your-lists-scroll-faster-than-the-wind)